# How am i able to display text and not get this error undefined all the time

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to display text randomly, I have made an array and then I wanted the text displayed in a overlay. Unfortunately the text that I see is `undefined`, even though I have made all the text ready to be displayed.

I am also wondering how am I able to have a delay for the text to be displayed, as when the video starts playing I would like the text to appear after 3 seconds.

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="Default Styles"/>
    <script>


      var videos = [
   {
      id: 1,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/wMBSO175eJw?autoplay=1",
      text: "special text for video one"
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/eHDTNmnEg38?autoplay=1",
      text: "special text for video two"
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/-gDfE0H_m_Q?autoplay=1",
      text: "special text for video three"
   },
   {
      id: 4,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZIG6y3qBllU?autoplay=1",
      text: "special text for video four"
   },
   {
      id: 5,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6GEp_UxdCUQ?autoplay=1",
      text: "special text for video five"
   },
   {
      id: 6,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/LiO5HiwVxnk?autoplay=1",
      text: "special text for video six"
   }

];

window.onload = function() {
   var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
   var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
   var previousId = localStorage.getItem("previousId");
   if (previousId) {
      var previousIndex = videos.findIndex(v => v.id === parseInt(previousId));
      videos.splice(previousIndex, 1);
   }
   var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
   localStorage.setItem("previousId", videos[current].id);
   localStorage.getItem("previousId");
   var randomVideoUrl = videos[current].url;
   player.setAttribute("width", "640");
   player.setAttribute("height", "390");
   player.setAttribute("src", randomVideoUrl);
   playerDiv.appendChild(player);
   var textContainer = document.getElementById("r_text");
   textContainer.innerHTML = videos[current].r_text;
};

      var r_text = new Array ();
      r_text[0] = "All leave are brown";
      r_text[1] = "fafwfaf";
      r_text[2] = "fakfjwkfkajwkfawjf";
      r_text[3] = "cornflakes";
      r_text[4] = "bannana";
      r_text[5] = "Choclate";
      r_text[6] = "lol";
      var i = Math.floor(7*Math.random())



    </script>
</head>


<div id="random_player">
  <div id="r_text">
  </div>
</div>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a `key` `r_text` in your video objects. There is no connection between the video array of objects and `r_text`.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve. But if you want to access the text from the video objects use `video[current].text` instead.

**EDIT :**  if you want to use the `r_text` values. Use `r_text[i]` as a value for the `text` key in the videos objects. And if you want to delay the appearance of the text you can use `setTimeout` like in the code below or css animations

Check below

```js
var r_text = new Array ();
      r_text[0] = "All leave are brown";
      r_text[1] = "fafwfaf";
      r_text[2] = "fakfjwkfkajwkfawjf";
      r_text[3] = "cornflakes";
      r_text[4] = "bannana";
      r_text[5] = "Choclate";
      r_text[6] = "lol";
      var i = Math.floor(7*Math.random())

var videos = [
   {
      id: 1,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/wMBSO175eJw?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/eHDTNmnEg38?autoplay=1",
      text:  r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/-gDfE0H_m_Q?autoplay=1",
      text:  r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 4,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZIG6y3qBllU?autoplay=1",
      text:  r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 5,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6GEp_UxdCUQ?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 6,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/LiO5HiwVxnk?autoplay=1",
      text:  r_text[i]
   }

];

window.onload = function() {

   var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
  
   var textContainer = document.getElementById("r_text");
   setTimeout(() => { 
    textContainer.innerHTML = videos[current].text;

    }, 3000)
   
};
```

```html
<div id="random_player">
  <div id="r_text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes i have already did that but i want the text to be displayed randomly therefore i made a new array where it will chose the text randomly and it won't be a static text for just that video if you know what i mean sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Check now the answer. Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: is there a way as well to delay the text to appear e.g. 3 seconds later.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with setTimeout in javascript ( see answer ) or use a css animation.